# Make JS change urls (using hashtag) when changing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I’m using this javascript code to animate and load my website!

```
$('.down-trigger').on('click', function () {
var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #container';
     $('#container').attr('id','to-go');
     $('#wrapper').append('<div id="newcontainer"/>');
     $('#newcontainer').load(toLoad, function () {
       $('#newcontainer').append($('#container').children()).css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '696px'});
       $('#to-go, #newcontainer').animate({top:'-=691'},600, function () {
         $('#to-go').remove();
         var lastchild = $('.page:last-child'); // ignore these lines
         var found = lastchild.find('div.slide'); // this one
         if (found.length == 0) { lastchild.remove(); } // and this one
         carousels(); // and this one too
       });
     $('#container').remove();
     $('#newcontainer').attr('id','container');
     searchform(); // these two lines can be ignored too
     triggers(); // this is the second line to ignore
   });
   return false;
});`
```

Could you guys help to change the url when the user clicks a link?

I know I have to use something like window.location.hash but i really don’t know where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.href = 'myNewUrl.html';
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what exactly is going on with your code.... you'd be the best to judge, but you put that wherever in your code you are ready to actually change to the next page.